# JavaScript return value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm learning JavaScript as my first language and I'm getting the idea here as far as functions go but I don't understand what the point of the return value at the end is.

What is it used for?

Comment: Learn the basics first. Google it.

Comment: To expand on what Baszz said, don't just Google "JavaScript return value", Google "JavaScript tutorial".

Comment: I'm watching the lynda JavaScript essentials 2011 course and all the guy said is you use the return if you want...

Answer (score 7):

To put it simply, a value is returned so you can use it elsewhere in your program. Consider the following (pretty pointless) function:

```
function addNumbers(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

When you call that function, you supply 2 arguments `x` and `y`. The function body adds those together and returns the result. You probably want to be able to use the result, so when you call the function you can assign the result to a variable:

```
var added = addNumbers(5, 10); //addNumbers returns 5 + 10
alert(added); //Alerts 15
```

And now that you have a variable `added` with the result of calling the function, you can use that anywhere else in the containing scope of that variable. That means you don't have to call `addNumbers(5, 10)` over and over again every time you want to use the result of it.

Comment: what would happen here if you didn't put return in the function

Comment: The function body would be executed, so any code in there will run, but the function would return `undefined`, so if you wanted to use the result of the function, as I've shown in the second snippet of code in my answer, it would alert `undefined` rather than the result.

Answer (score 2):

The return value is passed back to whatever called the function.

```
function myFunction() { return 1; }

alert(myfunction()); // alerts 1
var foo = myFunction(); // assigns 1 to foo
```

Answer (score 2):

The return stamenet finish the method and returns the value for the caller.

Answer (score 2):

A function performs a task of some sort. Sometimes you need to see the result of a task, and sometimes you don't. Run this code for example:

```
function multiply(a, b)
{
    return a * b;
}

alert( multiply(2, 2) );
```

The return value of multiply() (in this case "4") will become the argument of the alert() function. This code will therefore show an alert box with the number 4 in it.